# Set value back to scope in directive after Bootstrap modal closed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm implementing a small page to create Invoice. In invoice, I have an invoice details array. It could be represented like this

```
invoice = {
userName: "Mr A",
invoiceDetails:[{
location: "0,0"
}]
}
```

I create a directive for the btnSelectLocation like this

```
invoiceManagementApp.directive("selectLocation", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).on("click", function () {
                $('#locationPickerModal').modal();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

So now, when locationPickerModal closed, how could I set back the value to "scope". Because the invoiceDetails is dynamically added or removed by user

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Why dont you use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ?

Comment: @lin because the project has been kicked off before thinking of using angularjs at this time...